# Erro An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' quando eu tento abrir o OpenFileDialog em um UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, usercontrol

Ola estou com um problema para abrir o OpenFileDialog dentro de um UserControl.

Eu tenho um UserControl que tem alguns botões, um desses botões abre um novo UserControl no estilho ContextMenuStrip, ele funciona normalmente, mas se eu tento abrir um OpenFileDialog dentro desse segundo UserControl ele da um erro
*“An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Tentativa de leitura ou gravação em memória protegida.
Normalmente, isso é uma indicação de que outra memória está danificada.”*

Fiz um projeto simples pra tentar mostar esse problema
[Download no GoogleDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zTiBdSJ2xutyT2MznzqN2SVt_KjBvatn/view?usp=share_link)

Esse é o código para mostar o segundo UserControl:

```
public UserControl Uc { get; set; }
    Form fm;
    bool isShow = false;


    public void ShowUc() {
        if (Uc == null || FindForm() == null)
            return;

        if (isShow)
        {
            CloseOptions();
            return;
        }


        Uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        fm = new Form();
        isShow = true;
        fm.Size = Uc.Size;

        fm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        fm.Controls.Add(Uc);
        fm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        fm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        fm.Deactivate += Fm_Deactivate; ;

        fm.Location = new Point(FindForm().Location.X + button1.Location.X - fm.Size.Width, FindForm().Location.Y + button1.Location.Y + this.Size.Height);

        fm.Show();
    }
    void CloseOptions() {
        isShow = false;
        if (fm != null)
        {
            fm.Controls.Clear();
            fm.Close();
        }
    }
    private void Fm_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CloseOptions();
    }
```

Eu não consegui entender porque o erro acontece, muito menos achar uma solução
Se alguém tiver alguma ideia do porque o erro esta acontecendo já ajuda muito

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Isso acontece porque quando voce chama o `OpenFileDialog`, o seu Form perde o foco para a nova janela e dispara o evento `Deactivate` que voce esta usando.

Coloque um `BreakPoint` nesse momento

```
private void Fm_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CloseOptions();
}
```

Seu metodo `CloseOptions` limpa todos os controles do Form, incluindo o UserControl que está ativo.